# Explicit uniform location has no effect

Tags: opengl, glsl

In a GLSL vertex shader I have:

```
#version 330
layout (location=0) uniform mat4 wm_;
layout (location=1) uniform mat4 vm_;
...more code...
```

I get no compile errors when the shader is compiled. Later, I am assert()ing on glGetUniformLocation for wm_ and vm_ returning the locations specified in the shader source. The asserions fire, as glGetUniformLocation returns different values (it do not return -1, that is, the uniforms don't get optimized away, they get assigned what appear to be valid but different locations.)

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Explicit uniform locations are supported since GLSL 4.30 or by extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location.
The compiler here is too tolerant and allows syntax that is not supported in GLSL 3.30
This should be considered as a driver bug.

Comment: You should mention how to enable the extension in GLSL.

Comment: Ah, thanks. For clarity, this is running on AMD, Catalyst control center reporting Catalyst version 13.1 and OpenGL version 6.14.10.12002.

Comment: To enable the extension add following line:  `#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : require`  just after the `#version`